# Calling webmethod not working through javascript. Error code 400 and 500

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest, webmethod

I am trying to call webmethod from xmlhttp object like this

```
 var v2 = JSON.stringify({ province: 'Ontario' });
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:49771/rentalone/lp.aspx/getCities?" + v2, true);
```

The problem is when I use "?" like this

```
  /getCities?" + v2
```

it gives me error code 500 "missing value for parameter"

but when I use "/"

```
   /getCities/" + v2
```

it gives me error code http 400. Bed request

How can I call webmethod that has input parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change it so that `v2='province=ontario';`?

Ok... that didn't work, so maybe try something like this (modified from the link in the comments):
    var v2 = JSON.stringify({ province: 'Ontario' });
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
http.open("POST", "http://localhost:49771/rentalone/lp.aspx/getCities", true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", v2.length);

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
   if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText);
   }
}
http.send(v2);
```

Comment: not even close. It's now saying unknown method getCities

Comment: So you are passing  "http://localhost:49771/rentalone/lp.aspx/getCities?province=Ontario"?

Comment: Then I guess you may need req.send().

Comment: ev ery thing is done. My request is sending but it saying parameter expected. how can I put parameter in url. I supposed parameter is in json format